# Is any List View with Scroll Bar for Jquery Mobile Device?

Tags: jquery

We are planed to develop Mobile Application software for all Device. So we are deside to make this on J query Mobile.

In That List view control is not have the Scroll Bar. And I am planned to use new rc3.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc3/docs/lists/lists-performance.html

Is any other jquery have List View with Scroll Bar and Datagrid.

If you know please help me.

I saw a youtube demo in that List View with Scroll Bar is there. I don't know the which software they use. I gave the image below.

[image]

Comment: I don't think jQuery Mobile is supposed to be responsible for rendering scroll bars, the web browser on the phone will do it. You scroll through the list like you scroll through a regular webpage.